# Creating Thumbnail Picture grid in Ember using Picnicss

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I'm working on a project using one of its component in picnicss that card.
I'm trying to build picture thumbnails like this:

```
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
```

Where x is a picture probably with 200px * 200px

When I tried the following:

```
<div class="row">
  {{#each model}}
    <div class="third">
      <article class="card">
        <img {{bind-attr src="someimage"}}>
      </article>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

It will not show all my images. How can I let `{{#each}}` know that every 7 data it will need to start a new row?

Comment: thanks guys for editing my question, sorry for  my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i answer my question.
I separate the data in the route using array, so array will have rows and column, then i can iterate the array in the template

Answer (score 0):

`model` hook inside the route should return the original data fetched from the external service (your backend).

**First Case**

You only need this data for specific one purpose, you can do the data format manipulation inside `afterModel` hook.

**Second Case**

The data is shared by multiple components inside the same route (URL). Let the component figure out how to display data by creating a computed property which formats the data based on your needs.